# Meteor.js - what is the most convenient way to update a user profile?

Tags: meteor

I find that I use the user profile extensively.  I would like to be able to do something like:

```
Meteor.user().profile.some_setting = 'something';
Meteor.user().update();
```

What is the most convenient way to update a user's profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor.user() is a document, not a cursor. It's actually an alias for `Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId)`.

You can either do so via a method call (server), or directly on the client.

Method call way:

```
//server code
Meteor.methods({
  updateProfile : function(newProfile) {
    if(this.userId)
      Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {$set : { profile : newProfile }});
  }
});
```

And on the client:

```
Meteor.call('updateProfile', myNewProfile);
```

I advise to do so through a server method, since the code runs in a cleaner environment.

If you want to do it directly on the client:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set : {profile : myNewProfile}});
```

(`Meteor.userId()` is an alias for `Meteor.user()._id`)
[More infos on the doc!](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_api)

Comment: Your method is good, but you can make it more efficient by using allows, then server only updates collection without any code running on it

Comment: Heh, true. I have a policy of "deny all, method everything" to be absolutely sure I control everything happening on the database. Should I edit my answer to have the "Allow" in?

Comment: Well, that's your call, I just mentioned it so some ppl know there is other way around ;p